# how to pass parameters to the main action of a controller in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url

I want to pass parameters to the main action of a controller like so :

```
http://www.site.com/controller/index/param1/param2
```

but I DON'T want to have to write the 'index' action. So :

```
http://www.site.com/controller/param1/param2
```

How can I do this in codeigniter ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify your `routes.php` as the route default would be to `controller/method`

And explicitly define your route of
`$route['blogs/(:any)/(:any)'] = "blogs/index/$1/$2";`

Word to the wise about routing, once you set down this path of 'prettying up' the controller/method, you will need to define it for all methods in your controller:

```
$route['blogs/load/(:any)'] = "blogs/load/$1";
$route['blogs/delete/(:any)'] = "blogs/delete/$1";
```

As you won't be able to just call `/blogs/load/4332` it will think 'load' is var 1 and '4332' is var 2.

Reference: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html